# Having difficulties understanding pointers in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

So I understand that in ObjC everything lives in the Heap, and everything has a pointer to it. I'm reading through O'Reilys book and I'm grasping most things, but when I'm following through the tutorials/examples and something like this comes up

`NSMutableArray *bar = [[[foo alloc] init] callMethod];`

The `*` is right next to `bar`, but then you have things like

`- (NSString *)createDeck:(NSString *)numOfCards;`

Why is `NSString *` and not `- (NSString)*createDeck:(NSString)*numOfCards;`?

Any help understand things concept would be great thanks.

Edit:

`NSUInteger *randomIndex = arc4random() % [deck count];`
[image: Error]

As Where
`NSUInteger randomIndex = arc4random() % [deck count];`
Works fine, how come removing the pointer in this case works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### tl;dr

The type is `NSString *` and that's why you have

```
- (NSString *)createDeck:(NSString *)numOfCards;
```

The return type and the argument type are enclosed within the parentheses.

Concerning the last question, an `NSUInteger` is not a object, despite the naming may suggest otherwise. Being a native type it lives on the stack and you don't need a pointer to it.

If you cmd-click on the type name, you'll find that it's actually a typedef for `unsigned int` (or `unsigned long`, depending on the architecture).

---

### Discussion

Variables in C (and consequently in Objective-C) are declared using declarators, which are composed by a type and an identifier. In your example `NSString *` is the type and `bar` is the identifier.

```
NSString * bar;
^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^
  type      identifier
```

Declarators without an identifier are called abstract declarators, and are commonly used in C in three cases:

- casting

  ```
    float x = (float)2/4;
  ```
- argument of `sizeof()`

  ```
    sizeof(int *);
  ```
- declaring argument types of a function

  ```
    void foo(int *, float);
  ```

In Objective-C they are also used for return and argument types of methods, and that's why you have

```
- (NSString *)createDeck:(NSString *)numOfCards;
```

(Most of the information about declarators are adapted from http://nilsou.com/blog/2013/08/21/objective-c-blocks-syntax/)

---

Concerning the position of the asterkisk,

```
NSString *bar;
NSString * bar;
NSString* bar;
```

are all valid ways in to declare a variable of type *pointer to NSString*, aka `NSString *`.

Which one to use is a pure matter of personal taste, even though I believe the first one is the most common.

Comment: Sorry I forgot half my question in the original post, if you could answer the edited portion, I'll gladly mark you as Answer.

Comment: This is great, good stuff! Very detailed and exactly what I needed!